# How to have .xlxm macro file mirror another file that is connected to Flows/Power Automate and updates? Equations?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I made a excel sheet that is connected with microsoft Flows/Power Automate to automatically update when a new answer is completed from Microsoft forms. It adds a new row with the survey responses.

The only issue is flow/power automate does not work with macro enabled excel files. So now I have an updating excel file, and the macro enabled excel file that needs to be connected to mirror the new responses added to the working flowed file.

[image: File with New responses up to 33]

[image: Macro enabled (with less responses, only to 31)]

I tried "=[FlowedGroupEvaluation.xlsx]Sheet1!$E$38" but it just gets me in a file loop of selecting and will keep popping up the file directory.

**Question:**
What is the best way/equation to get my macro file to mirror the flowed file? Or if I must use equations, what should I use (I dont know much about moving cells)? I need this to update by itself and continuously mirror.
They are separate docs, FlowedGroupEvaluation.xlsx, and FlowedGroupEvaluationWithMacroFinal.xlxm

Files attached:
With macro:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ahxqhc08WSfqiXBlIHKA6b-Yj1rk?e=aFGHHR

Without:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ahxqhc08WSfqiXZPGbKJJ0MbxWc8?e=YkQ5vm

Comment: Instead of doubling the data, why not just have the macro file target the flow file and edit the data inside there. I often write macro files whose only job is to run a specific function on an open book and then close itself. Use `Application.Workbooks("Name")` to reference an open workbook.

Answer (score 0):

To copy all the data, the simplest path would be to use the `Sheets.Copy` method and looping though each sheet you want to copy. To remove duplicates from the destination file, you can use the `Sheets.Delete` method.

Its slow and suboptimal but it would ensure you have a flawless duplicate of the most current set of data.

It would look something like this:

```
Sub CopyAll()
    Dim Flow As Workbook, newSheet As Worksheet, oldSheets() As Worksheet
    
    Set Flow = Application.Workbooks("FlowWorkbookName")
    
    ReDim oldSheets(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    
    'Gather the old sheets into an array
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set oldSheets(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    Next i
    
    'Copy over the new stuff
    For Each newSheet In Flow.Worksheets
        newSheet.Copy Before:=oldSheets(1)
    Next newSheet
    
    'Delete the old stuff
    'suppress the warning message about deleteing sheets.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To UBound(oldSheets)
        oldSheets(i).Delete
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Call YourOtherFunctions
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't make the current xlsx file have a macro, but if I can add another macro to the already macro file to copy the other worksheet, then this could work.